# Secure hostname/Serial number through puppet before signing certs

Tags: puppet

How can I restrict other nodes or apply some security check to in my domain.For example I had two
systems where one is connected with the puppet server for receiving updates & for second system's
I change the hostname to "test.example.com" & configure the system similar to the first system & runs puppetd -td --waitforcert 60 where it receives the updates from the puppet server.

I want to restrict the same as I mentioned in my example with nodes within the domain & outside the domain.How can this be achieved   ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Turn off autosigning of certs for new nodes (so that you can verify that the request is legitimate before the client gets access to the master), and make sure the `node_name` option is set to `cert` so that Puppet uses only trusted information (the CN in the cert, which you've verified is correct) rather than data which can be spoofed (everything provided by facter).

Comment: Actually there are 3000+ nodes in my domain & disabling autosign will be a tedious task.Is there any way I can compare "dmidecode -s system-serial-number" & "facter |grep hostname|cut -d ' ' -f 3" through puppet so that if anyone changes hostname from within or outside the domain    ?

Comment: also all the node's hostnames are set to system's serial number & I want the same to be persistent in the domain.

Comment: You can do whatever you want.  But if you trust anything coming from the client, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: If you deploy systems so regularly that you can't sign the certificates by hand, consider modifying your bootstrapping system to create the certificate (using cert --generate) and deploy it to the system.

Comment: Also,I am trying to override a hostname.rp from path: /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/facter as,

Facter.add(:hostname) do
  confine :hostname => "serialnumber"
  setcode do
    Facter::Util::Resolution.exec('cat /sys/power/states')
  end
end

Is the fact code correct as I want puppet to pick serialnumber instead of hostname from facter ?

Thanks

Comment: Questions go in questions, not comments.